# Missing/disappearing Drupal tabs

Tags: drupal, menu, tabs

In my code, I create some tabs using MENU_LOCAL_TASK.
Sometimes for some unknown reasons, the tabs disappears for some users.
I have the similar codes from other Drupal or contributed modules.

The only remedy that I can do is to truncate all cache tables and do menu_rebuild().
Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 6.16? There is an issue in versions before that that may cause the menu table to not be rebuilt 100%, thus a locking framework was introduced in 6.16.

I have seen this issue myself where sections of the admin section will vanish and clearing the cache or calling menu_router_build() is the only way to bring it back.